# Jenkins fails to parse POM on Mac

Tags: android, jenkins

I am setting up CI with Jenkins on my Mac mini, but after all the configuration I get this error :

```
    ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.

    IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/mavenTest/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
        at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
        at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:773)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:353)
        at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:234)
        at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:235)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:729)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1603)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:506)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
        ... 12 more
```

This is Android project and should work, because I downloaded working sample from Maven related website. Any ideas?

edit :

in previous lines i get :

```
JDK installation skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x
JDK installation skipped: Unknown CPU name: mac os x
```

and I guess that's the problem. I see that I cannot use "install automaticaly JDK" on Mac, so I have to do it by hand, the problem is that path which is suppose to be good, returns error `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands doesn’t look like a JDK directory`.
Path is : `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/`

Comment: I get another path from Eclipse preferences (found that it is using other path) - `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`, now Jenkins stops at the begining and don't even compile

Comment: Do you think it's related to the "." in the file path?Try to put it somewhere else